# PDF generation from an html containing images and text

Tags: java, html, imagemagick, pdf-generation

I am looking for a fast and efficient way to create pdf from my website. The pdf will have images along with some text that I can pass as an html. The pdf could simply be a printed format of the html I pass. Something that is similar to what CutePDF does. Is it possible? How? Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really its possible just one week before i did it. I was used java, servlet and jsp to did the same.

### Steps :

1. Read the html file and have it in string.
2. Use ITextRenderer for converting html to pdf
3. set render document from string using setDocumentFromString()
4. Then create pdf using createPDF() method

   - you can store pdf in specified path or output stream, i have used output stream

### Sample Code :

```
Visit http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/06/26/generating-pdfs-with-flying-saucer-and-itext.html
protected void doProcess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response){
    response.setContentType("application/pdf;");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Filenametodownload.pdf");       
    String reportContent = "<html><body><b>This is sample HTML</b></body></html>";
    ServletOutputStream sos =null;
    try {
        sos = response.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e1) {          
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    String st = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    // ITextRenderer is only works fine with compailed version of core-renderer.jar 
    //Jar available in http://wo-repository.doit.com.br/content/repositories/thirdparty/org/xhtmlrenderer/core-renderer/R8-final/
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();   
    //System.out.println(reportContent);
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(reportContent);
    renderer.layout();
    try {
        renderer.createPDF(sos);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {         
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {       
        sos.close();
        session.removeAttribute("ReportContent");
    } catch (IOException e) {           
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Note : include itext.jar and core-renderer.jar

Try this way u can do... All the best...

Answer (score 3):

Try using `wkhtmltopdf` which serves most of the cases. You have to install this little exe / rpm. It uses `webkit` engine to render the `html` in a `headless browser mode`  first and converts the webpage to pdf. Once you install you can call it through your java/php application. Its worth installing.

Here is the link:http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/.

PS: I don't work for `wkhtmltopdf` :) , I tried several others like itext in one of my projects but non worked as efficient as this tool.

Comment: Yes.. it renders, it generates the pdf with exact look and feel when you render the html in a browser (chrome uses webkit).

Comment: +1 We use `wkhtmltopdf` in production since 2 years now, and it is great. You can have a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) too

Comment: Sure will try `phantomjs`.. looks interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the HTML->PDF conversion on the server side, and provided your server code is already in Java or C#/.NET, you could use [XMLWorker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xmlworker/) from iText. Here's a [demo-page](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/) and some [documentation](http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/index.html) (which is outdated, but should be updated soon).

OTOH, if you want to carry out the conversion on the client side, what about a PDF printer? My personal favorite is [PDFCreator](http://www.pdfforge.org/). Note that using a PDF printer is only a solution for you, not for any user browsing your website.

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to install tools like WKHTMLTOPDF but still need full CSS, HTML, and Javascript capabilities, you could use [Sprint PDF](http://www.sprintpdf.com). It's an online API that comes with tons of options.